# How to add image slider with navigation onclicking particular image..image carousel package is not working

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using image carousel package to display network images inside container with sliding option.. but on clicking on image navigation is not working..using Inkwell, Gesture we are able to give to container not for particular image...

Is there any alternate for showing network images inside container with sliding option like image carousel

code:

```
return new Column(children: <Widget>[                                   
                                  new SizedBox(                                     
                                       height: 200.0,
                                        width: 350.0,
                                        child: new ImageCarousel(
                                          t1,
                                       interval: new Duration(seconds: 5),
                                          allowZoom: false,
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
```

Answer (score 1):

You try this example

```
 Card(
            elevation: 4.0,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    // photo and title
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 250.0,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Container(
                            child: new Carousel(
                              images: [


                                new NetworkImage("your Imgpath",),

                                new AssetImage(
                                  'assets/brake.png',
                                  // package: destination.assetPackage,
                                ),
                                new AssetImage(
                                  'assets/chris.jpeg',
                                  // package: destination.assetPackage,
                                ),
                                new AssetImage(
                                  'assets/clutch.png',
                                  // package: destination.assetPackage,
                                ),
                                new AssetImage(
                                  'assets/electrical.png',
                                  // package: destination.assetPackage,
                                ),
                                new AssetImage(
                                  'assets/engine.png',
                                  // package: destination.assetPackage,
                                ),
                              ],
                              boxFit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                              showIndicator: true,
                              dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
                              dotColor: Colors.grey,
                              dotSize: 5.0,
                              autoplay: false,
                            ),


                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550833/how-to-write-clickable-functions-for-slider-images-of-image-carousel-package-in/49587324#49587324). You can use the following code.

```
  import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class ImageCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<ImageProvider> imageProviders;
  final double height;
  final TargetPlatform platform;
  final Duration interval;
  final TabController tabController;
  final BoxFit fit;

  // Images will shrink according to the value of [height]
  // If you prefer to use the Material or Cupertino style activity indicator set the [platform] parameter
  // Set [interval] to let the carousel loop through each photo automatically
  // Pinch to zoom will be turned on by default
  ImageCarousel(this.imageProviders,
      {this.height = 250.0, this.platform, this.interval, this.tabController, this.fit = BoxFit.cover});

  @override
  State createState() => new _ImageCarouselState();
}

TabController _tabController;

class _ImageCarouselState extends State<ImageCarousel> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = widget.tabController ?? new TabController(vsync: this, length: widget.imageProviders.length);

    if (widget.interval != null) {
      new Timer.periodic(widget.interval, (_) {
        _tabController.animateTo(_tabController.index == _tabController.length - 1 ? 0 : ++_tabController.index);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SizedBox(
      height: widget.height,
      child: new TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: widget.imageProviders.map((ImageProvider provider) {
          return new CarouselImageWidget(widget, provider, widget.fit, widget.height);
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CarouselImageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final ImageCarousel carousel;
  final ImageProvider imageProvider;
  final BoxFit fit;
  final double height;

  CarouselImageWidget(this.carousel, this.imageProvider, this.fit, this.height);

  @override
  State createState() => new _CarouselImageState();
}

class _CarouselImageState extends State<CarouselImageWidget> {
  bool _loading = true;

  Widget _getIndicator(TargetPlatform platform) {
    if (platform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      return new CupertinoActivityIndicator();
    } else {
      return new Container(
        height: 40.0,
        width: 40.0,
        child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    widget.imageProvider.resolve(new ImageConfiguration()).addListener((i, b) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _loading = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      height: widget.height,
      child: _loading
          ? _getIndicator(widget.carousel.platform == null ? defaultTargetPlatform : widget.carousel.platform)
          : new GestureDetector(
        child: new Image(
          image: widget.imageProvider,
          fit: widget.fit,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          int index = int.parse(_tabController.index.toString());
          switch(index){
            //Implement you case here
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            default:
              print(_tabController.index.toString());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: new ImageCarousel(
        <ImageProvider>[
          new NetworkImage(
              'http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/images/images-2.jpg'),
          new NetworkImage(
              'http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/images/images-10.jpg'),
          new NetworkImage(
              'http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/images/images-4.jpg'),
        ],
        interval: new Duration(seconds: 5),
      )
    ),
  ));
}
```